# In OpenCL C supports functions as a member in structure or not?

Tags: c, opencl, intel

At present I have been working on OpenCL C(2.0) in Intel HD graphics 530.  Whenever I am trying in function as a member in structure at kernel side, it is giving the error.

My question:

a) OpenCL C: will it support a function as a member in structure or not. If it is possible, please send the any link.

In normal C compilers, function pointers are supported; in OpenCL C(2.0),  will it support them or not?

Comment: Most likely it will not. As far as I remember, OpenCL kernel language allows only static code dispatch: it does not support choosing which function to call at runtime.

Comment: thank you for valuable information